# Osascript in Yosemite broken/slow - anyone can confirm?

Tags: macros, applescript, osx-yosemite

During 10.8 times I created macro in Keyboard Maestro for adding web pages to Reminders list to read them later.

In Mountain Lion and Maverics it worked fine but in Yosemite something wrong is going on resulting very slow executions.

Previously execution time was about 1-2 seconds now its over 40 seconds or even one minute!

Apple team provided me with wrong solution ordered to "code sign" my script, but there is no "file" to codesign and applescripts can be executed in command line. So IMO they messed up something in osascript and still couldn't fix it till 10.10.4. But I need someone to confirm or to advice me how to debug problem, because I cannot find in system console log lines relevant to problem.

UPDATE:
On El Capitan 10.11.1 problem still persist.

[Macro](https://www.dropbox.com/s/16wn7opllfls372/Add%20Current%20Page%20in%20Chrome%3ASafari%20to%20Reminders.kmmacros?dl=0)

Could anyone test and confirm this? I provided link to macro.
It is bind currently to F1 - change as you like. Before execution create "2Read" list in Reminders on OSX.

Comment: Have you tried running your AppleScript code outside of KM - e.g. in Script Editor and via `osascript` - to see if the same performance problem occurs there? That should be your first step in narrowing down the cause.

Comment: If you want to monitor Apple event traffic, quit Reminders.app then run the following in a new Terminal window: `export AEDebugSends=1; export AEDebugReceives=1; /Applications/Reminders.app/Contents/MacOS/Reminders`. Then do the same for Keyboard Maestro. Now when you run scripts in KM, you should see everything that goes back and forth between them. (Annoyingly events are not datestamped when logged, and you'll have to wade through lots of noise and raw four-char codes, but it's better than nothing.)

Comment: @foo  Running the same script in Script Editor is about 1-2 seconds so it has to be something weird in osascript. Will try next to monitor traffic from KM and Reminders

Comment: I check and still have no clue..I cannot read this output. Maybe you will be more clever than me. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WhbAE5tA

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and it's done in about 1-2 seconds on my machine. So I do not experience the same problem as you.

I'm running OS X 10.10.4 on a late 2013 MBP Retina.

Maybe your "2Read" list is too long?

**Another tip:**

I used to have a problem with long lists in Applescript, too. Sometimes it would take minutes to run through a list, but after using some if [these tips](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-07.html) the time for the lists was brought back to only seconds.

Comment: The OP's code is controlling Reminders.app's object model, not manipulating AppleScript lists, so this has nothing to do with the latter's notoriously inefficient behavior. (p.s. The AppleScript subroutines at the macosxautomation are total garbage, even by AppleScript standards. Digging around the macscripter.net site is a slightly better prospect as there's at least some chance of finding fast, reliable solutions in amongst the inevitable dross.)

Comment: I've tested it on empty "2Read" list - the same effect. I thought it may be caused by several developer preview updates so I installed 10.10.4. Combo Update - the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

From your pastebin link (yeah, I did warn you it'd look like mince):

---

#### Keyboard Maestro event logs

(1) KM sends an 'open' event ('aevt/odoc') to Growl, telling it to open a temp file (presumably to make Growl display a message)

(2) Bartender sends a 'get scripting terminology' event ('ascr/gdut') to KM

(3) Bartender sends a 'BTDR/Load' event to KM, which looks like Bt telling KM to load a plugin named "BartenderHelperNinetyOne.bbundle"

(4) KM send a 'KeyC/KeyB' event to something (it doesn't give the name of the process, only its Process Serial Number, which is the classic MacOS equivalent to a Unix process ID). Probably easiest just to ask the KM devs about that one.

(5,6,7) KM then sends three 'application died' events ('aevt/obit') to Keyboard Maestro Engine (I'm guessing that's a faceless helper app that runs constantly in the background), informing it that three osascript processes (PSNs 312312, 315315, 316316) have terminated. This doesn't necessarily mean that osascript has crashed as those events contain an error number ('errn') parameter with value 0, and command-line processes normally return error code 0 to indicate they've completed successfully. It's quite likely these are normal internal notifications sent between KM and KME to indicate when a task is completed. The first of those osascript processes (PSN 312312) is related to the Reminders activity below; the other two I'm guessing are you running other AppleScript macros and probably not relevant here.

#### Reminders event logs

(1,2,3) The 'osascript' process with PSN 312312 sends Reminders a 'make' ('core/crel') event and two 'set' ('core/setd') events, which is obviously your AppleScript being run.

(4) The Dock sends it a 'reopen' ('aevt/rapp') event, which is probably just you clicking on Reminders' dock icon to bring it to the front.

---

The main problem, of course, is that without timestamps I can't tell you where your 40-second delay is occurring. You'd really need to do it again, this time manually noting the time at which each message is logged. And if you see a single 40-second delay somewhere in the middle, it should easy enough to determine which events it's occurring inbetween, which should start to point towards a cause. At which point, you're probably best contacting the KM vendor to discuss it with them.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. I try to contact KM devs. I should really run two windows side by side and then some clock and make a movie perhaps :)